# How to display graphs in a slider using Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-viewpager

I would like to display set of graphs in a slider view in Android. I tried with ViewPager for images. But I am not getting how to apply the same for Graphs. Is there any separate way to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "But I am not getting how to apply the same for Graphs" -- please explain what you have tried and what specific problems you have encountered. A `ViewPager` offering paging through images (via `ImageView`) is not significantly different than a `ViewPager` offering paging through editors (via `EditText`) or offering paging through complex layouts. If there is something specific about your chosen graphing library that is making this difficult, please explain what it is.

Comment: I am generating the graphs dynamically with some real time data. I would like to display the graphs in slider. I mean in slide one I need to display one graph and in the second slide I need to display second graphs and similarly for rest of the graphs. This is what my requirement is ?

Comment: Create a `PagerAdapter` that adapts whatever views you are using for your graphs, then put that `PagerAdapter` in the `ViewPager`. This is not significantly different than putting anything else in a `ViewPager`. If you are having specific problems implementing this, then edit your question, provide a [mcve] demonstrating what you have tried, and explain **in detail** what problems you are encountering.

Comment: Sure, let me try this procedure. Thank you